# Перевести генерируемый список в строку

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет!

```
    for i in range(len(state)):
    if 'Сейчас играет' in state[i]:
        for nname in range(len(name)):
            for rrang in range(len(rang)):
                local_column.append(f'{i} {name[i]} {rang[i]}')

        print(local_column[-1])
```

Вывод:

```
2 Asan 3
7 Ocean 3
```

При `print(type(local_column))` - list, при `print(type(local_column[-1]))` -- str соответственно

Вопрос, как перевести это "чудо" в нормальный рабочий код? При `print(local_column)` забивает консоль всем списком несколько раз, то есть "2 asan 3 2 asan 3  2 asan 3  2 asan 3  2 asan 3 "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде два последних цикла `for` лишние

```
for i in range(len(state)):
    if 'Сейчас играет' in state[i]:
        local_column.append(f'{i} {name[i]} {rang[i]}')

print(local_column)
```